# Ways to make a voice call from a web page?

Tags: html, voice, skype, google-talk

My app will look like this: two people enter a chat or something else in a page and have a skype name or Gtalk. Is it possible to make an anchor to call a voice client from the web page? Is there a flash fallback for this?

I know the skype: prefix that actually doesn't work for me in Ubuntu, but should work for Windows users.

I primarily target PCs & macs, but supporting mobile platforms with a solution will be nice.

**For Downvoters**: any comments why you do this? Please bother to explain me the obvious thing that I don't know and make this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is much too complex. Instead of answering it, which would take several pages, the person might as well write the application him/herself and sell it.

You have to divide your problem in tiny bits, and have a question for each one.

You could at least start with looking at gTalk API and Skype API to see what you need yourself.